# implement `executeUsingPATH()` in C

Tags: c, string, vector

I have a question, which is as follows. Can someone please explain to me?

Consider environment variables used in Unix-based operating systems. A frequently seen environment variable is named `PATH` and is used by command interpreters, or shells, to identify the names of directories to be searched to find executable programs. For example, a typical value of `PATH` may be `/Users/chris/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:.`, which provides a colon-separated list of directories to search for a required program.

Write a C99 function, named `executeUsingPATH()`, which accepts the name of a program to execute and a `NULL`-pointer terminated vector of arguments to be passed to that program. The requested program may be specified using just its name, or with either an absolute or a relative pathname.

`int executeUsingPATH(char *programName, char *arguments[]);` Function `executeUsingPATH()` should attempt to execute `programName` from each
directory provided via PATH, in order. If `programNam`e is found and may be executed (passing to it the indicated program arguments), the function should wait for its execution to terminate, and then return the exit status of the terminated process. If the function cannot find and execute `programName`, then it should simply return the integer `-1.` Your function should not simply call the similar library function named `execvp()`.

I have no idea about how to implement it.

Answer (score 0):

One thing to consider is that PATH may contain empty components, which denote the current directory. All in all, your assignment is rather straightforward - see inline comments.

```
int executeUsingPATH(char *programName, char *arguments[])
{
    switch (fork())
    {           siginfo_t info;
    case -1:    return -1;  // failure
    case  0:    break;      // execute child below
    default:    waitid(P_ALL, 0, &info, WEXITED);
                return info.si_status;
    }
    // the following is executed in the child process
    char *path = getenv("PATH");
    char pathname[PATH_MAX];
    size_t n;
    for (; ; )
    {
        n = strcspn(path, ":");         // calculate directory name length
        strncpy(pathname, path, n);     // copy directory name to pathname
        path += n;                      // skip over directory name
        if (n) pathname[n++] = '/';     // append '/' unless name is empty
        strcpy(pathname+n, programName);// append name of a program
        execv(pathname, arguments);     // try to execute the program
        if (!*path++) exit(-1);         // failure if no more directories
    }
}
```

Comment: that's correct but could you explain me what it is doing thanks in advance

Comment: Hm - it's doing what the assignment requested, and I already tried to explain with comments. What precisely would you like me to further explain?